# Determine if these correspondences on ${\mathbb Q}$ define functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Given the correspondence $f: \Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q$, explain why $f$ is a function:

> a) $$f\left( \frac pq\right) = \frac {3p}{3q} $$
>
> b) $$f\left( \frac pq\right) = \frac {3p^2}{7q^2}- \frac pq $$

I have a basic clue of how this is supposed to work, but I can't seem to put all the steps together. I know that to prove well-definition rigorously, we suppose $\frac pq$ = $\frac {p'}{q'}$, thus $pq'=p'q$. However, I'm not sure where to go from here - would anybody help me with these two? Thank you in advance for your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the Question here might more properly be framed as showing these expressions "well-define" a function $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$.  As far as I can tell there's no distinction to be drawn between "function" and "mapping" in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think you're right - my question is: how can you prove that these functions (and/ or mapping depending on however you want to say it) are well defined.

Comment: Please then revise your question. And, as long as $q \neq 0$ both of the functions are well-defined.

Comment: I think we need to prove that if $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$. For example, $f(p/q)=q$ is not a mapping, because $f(1/2)=2$ but $f(2/4)=4$, despite the fact that $1/2=2/4$.

Answer (score 2):

Number 1 is simple since $f(\frac{p}{q}) = \frac{3p}{3q} = \frac{p}{q}$ we have $f(x) = x$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, which clearly satisfies $x=y \Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$.

Number 2 is a bit more tricky, but really all you have to do is like you wrote your self, prove that if $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{p'}{q'}$ (which is (as you wrote) the same as $pq'=p'q$), then $f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = f\left(\frac{p'}{q'}\right)$.

I suggest that you try doing it yourself, by if you are unable I have included a short proof:

> Assume $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{p'}{q'}$, then $pq'=p'q$. Look at $f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$: $f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = \frac{3p^2}{7q^2}-\frac{p}{q} = \frac{3p^2}{7q^2}-\frac{7pq}{7q^2} = \frac{3p^2-7pq}{7q^2}.$ Now look at $(3p^2-7pq)7q'^2$: $(3p^2-7pq)7q'^2 = 21p^2q'^2-49pqq'^2 =21 (pq')^2 - 49 (pq')(qq') = 21 (p'q)^2 - 49 (p'q)(q'q) = 21 p'^2q^2-49p'q'q^2 = (3p'^2-7p'q')7q^2$ where the third equality comes from the identity $pq'=p'q$. All this proves that $f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) =\frac{3p^2-7pq}{7q^2} = \frac{3p'^2-7p'q'}{7q'^2}= f\left(\frac{p'}{q'}\right)$, which was what we wanted to prove!

Comment: Just so I get a better understanding, how are these two equal? (especially since the additions of the p' instead of p)
$21(pq′)2−49(pq′)(qq′)=21(p′q)2−49(p′q)(q′q)$

Comment: So $pq' = p'q$ (since $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{p'}{q'}$), this gives us that $21(pq')^2 = 21(p'q)^2$. And $qq' = q'q$ by multiplicative commutativity ($ab = ba$). So we also get $49(pq')(qq') = 49(p'q)(q'q)$. Subtract these two results to get the wished equality: $21(pq')^2 - 49(pq')(qq') = 21(p'q)^2 - 49(p'q)(q'q)$.